# How do I model a cave with realistic textures that show dirt and imperfections in the floor and walls?

Tags: texturing, sculpting, displacement, vertex-groups, brushes

I modeled a cave by starting with a cube, subdividing it, increasing the size and flattening the bottom. It looks like this now:
[image]

Using dyntopo I made the walls and floors all scratched and scuffed up.
[image]

I separated the floor and all of the other vertices by placing them in separate vertex groups. I used a ground texture for the floor vertex group and a rocky texture for the other vertex group.
[image]

I was frustrated because it looked bad. I figured it would be more realistic if I used a color ramp to make the ground texture stick to the lower points of the bumpy floor, and the rocky texture stick to the higher points of the bumpy floor. To do this, I used a texture coordinate node, a separate xyz node, a color ramp node, and a mix shader.
[image]

This worked in the sense that the ground now had dirt on the bottom parts and rock on the top parts but it still looks terrible.
[image]

There are 2 obvious problem that I see with this scene. The first is that I think the dyntopo sculpt job looks really bad. Idk if there's a better tool or if I'm just doing it wrong. This is a wide shot of the cave after I finished sculpting.
[image]

Maybe I need to buy some good brushes?

The second problem is the fact that the textures look bad. The patchiness on the floor doesn't look right and the displacement isn't actually displacing the surfaces. Does anyone know how I can imporve this? Here is a link to the Blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CL4QPdn1yh7KqTBDYCLes4zKB1ZRN8ak/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Please do not use google drive links in your question. You can share your file at https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The node group that you're using has a setting for the displacement strength. It's set to 0. That's why there is no rendered displacement. Furthermore, the displacement requires geometry. It doesn't work very well together with DynTopo because if you use this feature the mesh will have a different density in certain areas. For the height map displacement, you want to have a uniform density. Better do a quad remesh and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier if needed.